# Getting an image url from Jquery using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jquery function that have many url for image ojbect.
How can i get the url of the image using javascript.
I want to make a test on the url

```
    if url=condition {//do something...
```

You can find below example of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#show_banners").showcase({
            css: {
                "margin-left": "auto",
                "margin-right": "auto"
            },
            animation: {
                type: "fade",
                interval: 4500,
                speed: 1800
            },
            images: [{
                url: "../images/content/example1.jpg",
                description: "example1",
                target: "_self",
                link: ""
            }, {
                url: "../images/content/example2.jpg",
                description: "example2",
                target: "_self",
                link: ""
            }, {
                url: "../images/content/example3.jpg...
```

The ID of the DIV is `show_banners`.

Comment: what exactly do you need here?

Comment: I want to extract the url of the current image using javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to extract a src from an image in JavaScript:

```
var img_src = document.getElementById('elementId').src;
```

in jQuery:

```
var img_src = $('#elementId').attr('src');
```

hope that helps.

Comment: The message returned when i do this is "undefined".

Comment: I need to getElementbyID of the show_banner,
then get the image url

Comment: try with jQuery: $('#elementId img').attr('src')

Comment: Just one thing,
your code helped me to get the image of the first URL , and when i press on the other images i keep getting the url of the first image.

Comment: Gal V ? are you still there ?

Comment: you may be using duplicated IDs ?

Comment: You should only have one element assigned with a unique id (using the `id` attribute); do not give multiple elements the same id. Try using the `class` attribute or even the `name` attribute itself.

Comment: you can also make an event listener to each image. try this code instead:
$(function(){ $('img').click(function(){ alert( $(this).attr('src') }); });

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
var image_array = []

for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {

  image_array.push({
    url: "../images/content/example"+i+".jpg",
    description: "example"+i,
    target: "_self",
    link: ""
  })

}
```

Change `i<=5` to the amount of rows you have. Then in the code you posted above put:

`images: image_array`